# laravel 5.6 bulk inserting json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, bulkinsert

I am trying to build an API to store and retrieve MCQ exam papers. I am using laravel resource class to send handle Json data. I need to insert 40 records into MySQL database in a single query without using multi dimensional arrays. Is there any method available?

Sample data from front end:

```
{
"data":[
    {
    "paper_id":"5",
    "question_no":"2",
    "question":"test insert code",
    "answer1":"answer1",
    "answer2":"answer2 ",
    "answer3":"answer3 ",
    "answer4":"Answer4 ",
    "answerC":"Correct Answer",
    "knowarea":"who knows!"

    },

    {
        "paper_id":"5",
        "question_no":"3",
        "question":"test insert code",
        "answer1":"answer1",
        "answer2":"answer2 ",
        "answer3":"answer3 ",
        "answer4":"Answer4 ",
        "answerC":"Correct Answer",
        "knowarea":"who knows!"

    },

    {
        "paper_id":"5",
        "question_no":"4",
        "question":"test insert code",
        "answer1":"answer1",
        "answer2":"answer2 ",
        "answer3":"answer3 ",
        "answer4":"Answer4 ",
        "answerC":"Correct Answer",
        "knowarea":"who knows!"

    },

    {
        "paper_id":"5",
        "question_no":"5",
        "question":"test insert code",
        "aanswer1":"answer1",
        "answer2":"answer2 ",
        "answer3":"answer3 ",
        "answer4":"Answer4 ",
        "answerC":"Correct Answer",
        "knowarea":"who knows!"

    }
]
```

}`

The front end send 40 such objects i need to bulk insert them into my database.
The below code is my controller store function,

```
`   $paper->paper_id = $request->input('paper_id');
    $paper->question_no = $request->input('question_no');
    $paper->question = $request->input('question');
    $paper->answer1 = $request->input('answer1');
    $paper->answer2 = $request->input('answer2');
    $paper->answer3 = $request->input('answer3');
    $paper->answer4 = $request->input('answer4');
    $paper->answerC = $request->input('answerC');
    $paper->knowarea = $request->input('knowarea');

    if($paper->save())
    {
        return new ExamPaperResource($paper);
    }
```

What are my choices for bulk inserting the data?

Comment: use eloquent insert method for bulk upload

Comment: And none of [the posts that are shown in this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+json+php+mysql+array) are relevant?

Comment: those posts are useful @chb but im looking for a laravel based solution. like eloquent or any other packages or built in features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. It inserted all 40 records with no problems.

```
$array = $request->all();
    foreach($array["data"] as $row)
    {
        Exam_Paper::create(['paper_id'      => $row["paper_id"],
                            'question_no'   => $row["question_no"],
                            'question'      => $row["question"],
                            'answer1'       => $row["answer1"],
                            'answer2'       => $row["answer2"],
                            'answer3'       => $row["answer3"],
                            'answer4'       => $row["answer4"],
                            'answerC'       => $row["answerC"],
                            'knowarea'      => $row["knowarea"],
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on your sample data, you can `json_decode` the data and then use a single `Model::insert()`:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "paper_id":"5",
      "question_no":"2",
      "question":"test insert code",
      "answer1":"answer1",
      "answer2":"answer2 ",
      "answer3":"answer3 ",
      "answer4":"Answer4 ",
      "answerC":"Correct Answer",
      "knowarea":"who knows!"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

// Controller.php
public function store($json)
{
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    Paper::insert($data);
}
```

That will create arrays from your json and then insert all the records at once.

Comment: i get this error when i run json_decode    `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, null given`

Comment: I got the way. You should pick the array `$json->data`, the value of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: Eloquent::insert()

Like example below.

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096'),
    array('name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048'),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);
```

Comment: I need to insert 40 records at once this method ill have to write 40 arrays. i am looking for a smaller code

Comment: no i need to insert 40 records at once. the data comes as a json object from front end if i am to insert it in your method wouldn't i have to write:  `array('name'=> 'coder') 40 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below

```
$jsonarray =json_decode(json_encode($b),TRUE); // $b=your json array
foreach ($jsonarray as $key => $value) 
{
 foreach ($value as $a => $b) 
  {
  $qry=DB::insert('insert into your_table(colomn_name1,colomn_name2)values(?,?)',[$b['indexname1'],$b['indexname2']]); //index name will be paper_id,question_no etc
  }
}
```

your code will look like this

```
public function bulkdata(Request $request)
  {

   $b=$request->input('data');
$jsonarray =json_decode(json_encode($b),TRUE);
foreach ($jsonarray as $key => $value) 
{

 foreach ($value as $a => $b) 
  {

  $qry=DB::insert('insert into yourtable(paper_id,question_no,question,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answerC,knowarea)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[$b['paper_id'],$b['question_no'],$b['question'],$b['answer1'],$b['answer2'],$b['answer3'],$b['answer4'],$b['answerC']$b['knowarea']);
  }
}         

}
```

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

insert select query with update models array field

```
$newModelsArray=ModelTable::where(....)->get();


            foreach ($newModelsArray as $objectItr) {

            $newObjectItr = $objectItr->replicate();
            $newObjectItr->field=newValue;
            $newObjectItr->save();
            }
```

and there you'll update and save in to the table (clone it back to the database)
->replicate() will clone the modelObject and the ->save() will add it to the database inside the loop !

Thanks 
Ali

Answer (score -1):

Use collect function and toJson() will give the output as JSON object which can easily parse.

```
collect([ 'x' => 3 ])->toJson();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.