# Input data to Laravel Restful API using JSON

Tags: json, laravel, rest, api

I'm trying to post some data to a Restful API in my application, but I don't have success when the JSON have more than one group of data.

This is my JSON Example:

```
  "data": [     {
        "client_id": "3",
        "veiculo_id": "3",
        "carreta1_id": "3",
        "carreta2_id": "3",
        "motorista1_id": "3",
        "motorista2_id": "3",
        "embarcador_id": "3",
        "inicioprevisao": "2018-10-10 11:00:00",
        "fimprevisao": "2018-10-10 18:00:00",
        "nroliberacao": "3"
     },     
       {
        "client_id": "4",
        "veiculo_id": "4",
        "carreta1_id": "4",
        "carreta2_id": "4",
        "motorista1_id": "4",
        "motorista2_id": "4",
        "embarcador_id": "4",
        "inicioprevisao": "2018-10-10 11:00:00",
        "fimprevisao": "2018-10-10 18:00:00",
        "nroliberacao": "4"
        }   
   ] }
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function storeapi(Request $request)
    {
      $array = $request->all();
        foreach ($array['data'] as $row) {
            return Sm::create([
                'client_id' => $row['client_id'],
                'veiculo_id' => $row['veiculo_id'],
                'carreta1_id' => $row['carreta1_id'],
                'carreta2_id' => $row['carreta2_id'],
                'motorista1_id' => $row['motorista1_id'],
                'motorista2_id' => $row['motorista2_id'],
                'embarcador_id' => $row['embarcador_id'],
                'inicioprevisao' => $row['inicioprevisao'],
                'fimprevisao' => $row['fimprevisao'],
                'nroliberacao' => $row['nroliberacao']    
            ]);
      }
}
```

Doing in this way, I have only the first block put in the Database, and I need the two blocks.
I follow this article, but not work correctly.
[laravel 5.6 bulk inserting json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861486/laravel-5-6-bulk-inserting-json-data)

Comment: Because you make `return` which in end stops further execution. Also in link you provided, you can't see return statement inside `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because you're using a `return` within the `foreach` loop. I'm guessing you're doing this because you want to `return` the IDs of the inserted elements, so it'd be better to go around like this:

```
$array = $request->all();
$insertedIds = [];
    foreach ($array['data'] as $row) {
        $newSm = Sm::create([
            'client_id' => $row['client_id'],
            'veiculo_id' => $row['veiculo_id'],
            'carreta1_id' => $row['carreta1_id'],
            'carreta2_id' => $row['carreta2_id'],
            'motorista1_id' => $row['motorista1_id'],
            'motorista2_id' => $row['motorista2_id'],
            'embarcador_id' => $row['embarcador_id'],
            'inicioprevisao' => $row['inicioprevisao'],
            'fimprevisao' => $row['fimprevisao'],
            'nroliberacao' => $row['nroliberacao']    
        ]);
        $insertedIds[] = $newSm->id;
  }
  //Now we can return an array with the inserted elements' IDs
  //In this case, since this is coming from a JSON, we'll answer the same way.
  return response()->json($insertedIds);
```

Comment: Problem solved. That's exactly what you said. Thank you so much!